# Testing with jUnit

Tags: java, junit

I have a class called Menu.java which is used as the interface for my program.

In this Menu.java class, I have a switch/case block which acts as my menu Options.

Basically, I want to use jUnit to test the output of each case in that switch/case block, but I'm struggling to find the best way to do it.

Is it best to have a seperate jUnit TestCase for each menu operation? and then use a single TestUnit to run all cases? Or is there a better way this can be done?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, each class has a corresponding test class. So you would have a MenuTest.java to match your Menu.java. This allows you to find quickly the tests that are associated with a particular file, because of the naming convention.

Then, ideally, each test would have one test method associated with it. So if your switch has 10 cases, you would end up with 10 test methods, one for each case. This allows you to isolate quickly the option that is failing, because you get feedback for each test individually.

Note that TestCase is JUnit 3. If possible, use JUnit 4 tests (org.junit.*), these are annotated with a [@Test](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html) annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a single test case for each possible work flow. Ideally you would have one assertion per test case, which is probably easier following that guideline. In general you want to keep your unit tests small and concise.

Then I would place all the test cases in the same test class as long as they belong to the same tested class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a single class for Menu.java (MenuTest.java).  I'd write a test case for each menu option.  If you have GUI stuff, separate it from the logic.

No need to test the GUI or its plumbing.

Answer (score 0):

If the method you are testing is receiving different parameters for this switch, consider using a parameterized test case. The advantage is that it's easier to keep track of what need to be changed if your switch changes:

Here is how it works with [TestNG](http://testng.org) (look up "parameterized test case" for JUnit)

```
// This method will provide data to any test method that declares that
// its Data Provider is named "test1"
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "Foo", new Integer(36) },
   { "Bar", new Integer(37)},
 };
}

// This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the
// Data Provider named "test1"
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String n1, Integer n2) {
 System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your case I'd use single test case for all options. You need something like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;
import your.project.Menu;

public class MenuTest {
@Test
public void testCase() {
Menu menu = new Menu();
assertEquals("1",menu.runCase("bar"));
assertEquals("2",menu.runCase("foo"));
//etc
}
}
```

Comment: It is really bad practice to include all your asserts in one test case. If the first one fails you have no idea if the rest would pass or fail. It also makes it impossible to make your test cases independent since they're all in one test method. See all the other responses.

Comment: @Kane I don't agree with you. The goal is to test specific method. So the test case is testing it and it doesn't matter how many asserts it requires. Also I see ugly to make unnecessary boilerplate methods each with it's own call of the same function with different params and expected result.

Comment: You can have more than one test case per method. In fact that is good practice because a given method may have many possible paths, and it's much better to have separate test cases. Stuffing all the asserts into one method leaves the problem I mentioned earlier: If one fails you don't know the status of asserts that come afterwards.

Comment: @Kane, actually, you don't need to worry about other problems. The purpose of case is to fail. If it fails, you know, you have a problem. yes, you don't know all problems, but you don't need to. Anyway you will fix them one by one. And if ANY of that cases will fail in the future, test will tell you about that.

Comment: You're intentionally restricting the amount of information testing can give you. If you have 10 test cases failing, why would you want to only be told about the first one? It's much better to have the whole picture; your bugfix strategy may be different if you know the entire method has a problem rather than just one test case. Anyway, test cases should be independent. Doing this means that all these test cases are artificially bo.ogether instead of being separate

Comment: @Kane they're not artificially together, they're testing the single method! Thought, agree about other points. But, not sure if additional information worth writing that many lines of code.

Comment: When I first started testing, I dumped everything in one method too. Who wants to write the same method-specific setup more than once? Then a mentor of mine pointed out that most code is write once, run many times, and putting in the extra effort up front ends up saving you time later on. I suppose it's a value judgement, but I have always found that putting in the extra effort pays off.